# Going to web root using SFTP

Tags: web-development, sftp

I have a personal dev box which has SSH running on it. I am using it as web development server. Although I can SSH, SCP and SFTP into it, using SFTP but it takes me to the user home directory. How do I go to the web root using SFTP? I believe I might have to expose the /var/www/ in order to do that? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a dedicated account to perform work on the development server you can set that user's home to /var/www

```
usermod -d /var/www username
```